# FileReader API to call images using same ID tag multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, file, api

I've been trying to figure out how I can have the HTML5 FileReader API
display the same image more than once on duplicate id's.

An example of the implantation is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2xES5/37/

A div gets created by click, and within each DIV created lies a call (id="list") to display images. Then when someone adds their images each newly created div contains the images.

But the problem is that the Filereader isn't recognizing multiple instances of the same div id.
It's only showing the images in one DIV where as I'd want the images repeated for each div.

Hopefully someone can send me towards the right path.
Thanks

---

Basic FileAPI: http://jsfiddle.net/2xES5/35/

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
// Great success! All the File APIs are supported.

} else {
alert('Sorry The HTML5 FileReader API is not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            // Render thumbnail.
         var span = document.createElement('span');
span.setAttribute('class', 'spin');
                  span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                    '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

        };
    })(f);




    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

//</script>
```

Comment: i find window.URL.createObjectURL() much faster and easier since i don't need the silly onload callback that FileReader does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with those edits, but please don't do that again.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution:

**Don't use duplicate `ID`s**

Per the HTML spec, ID is meant to be *unique* in the document.

You'll notice that the API refers to:

`document.getElementById` -- note the singular element.

You'd be better off using either a CSS class name and selecting from it, or using a `data-` attribute, and selecting from that.

**If you insist upon using a duplicate `ID` anyways:**

`document.querySelectorAll("#list");` -- This will deal with the invalid code of multiple IDs.

**Update per comments**

Both the `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.querySelectorAll` return a **node list** -- an array-like structure that must be looped through.

*From your usage, it seems like you come from a jQuery background, which hides all of that from by turning everything into an array and applying jQuery methods to that array.  Straight JavaScript doesn't work like that.*

When trying to figure out why things don't work in JavaScript, it is always a good idea to look at the value have.  That will tell you a LOT.

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("#list");
console.log(nodeList);
console.log(nodeList.toString());
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  var node = listList[i];

   var span = document.createElement("span");
   span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("A span!");
   node.insertBefore(span, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the Trick.
Thanks!

```
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>



<script>
 window.preview = function (input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    $(input.files).each(function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(this);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(".list").append("<img class='thumb' src='" + e.target.result + "'>");
        }
    });
}
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/qF7Ff/1/